# RAISERROR never caught using EF 6 with proper severity

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I feel like I'm about to scrap this whole project and start over with the amount of frustration this is bringing me. So I definitely appreciate any insight anyone has...

I have SQL Server Stored Procedures that need to do certain logical checks in order to proceed. If these checks fail, RAISERROR() is called and the SP returns. Here's an example of one of these checks:

```
IF DATALENGTH(@LastName) < 2
BEGIN
    SELECT @err_msg = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(200), @LastName);
    RAISERROR('The "Single / Last Name" param provided is too short: %s',16,1, @err_msg);
    RETURN;
END
```

This SP is imported into a C# project using EF 6 model-first. The SP is imported into the Function Imports section of the model. An example of the above SP imported  (simplified parameters):

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> CreatePendingContact(string lastName)
    {
        var lastNameParameter = lastName != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("LastName", lastName) :
            new ObjectParameter("LastName", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<int>>("CreatePendingContact", lastNameParameter);
    }
```

And this function can be called in C# code with a try/catch block is called like so (where _model is the EF-generated dbContext subclass):

```
try
    {
        var result = _model.CreatePendingContact(
            LastName
            );
    }
catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
```

Right now I should be able to pass LastName = "" (or anything else < 2 chars) and get back an SqlException with the above RAISERROR text - however **nothing I have been able to do has gotten this SqlException to trigger when it should!**

So far here are the things I've tried:

- Using THROW keyword instead of simply RETURN (nothing caught)
- Running SQL Server Profiler, grabbing the query the C# client sends, and manually executing it in SSMS (results in the error being shown correctly in output)
- Modifying the EF generated to add a try/catch block at the ExecuteFunction<>() line (nothing caught)

Right now most threads online either fix the issue with a severity level set to 16, so I'm at a loss to what else I should be setting or looking for...

Comment: See http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part3.html#AllResultSets

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I've implemented, but it doesn't feel clean. Also, I don't get why I would have to make these edits to the generated code in order to catch the SqlException - if anyone has improvements it would definitely be welcome:

Part 1: Ensure your imported function under "Function Imports" of your model is set to return a collection of 'none' as the option. (I haven't gotten to SPs that return objects yet)

Part 2: Modify your EF-generated function code from the return line above into:

```
try
{
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("CreatePendingContact", lastNameParameter);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.InnerException is SqlException) { throw ex.InnerException; }
    else { throw; }
}
```

This change will only forward SqlExceptions, while still throwing locally for all other exceptions. This is the super-simple case, but it seems to work so far...

Comment: That's correct, what EF throws for your RAISEERROR is just not `SqlException` you are trying to catch.

Answer (score 0):

When I did a test proc with Your sample code

```
IF DATALENGTH(@LastName) < 2
BEGIN
    SELECT @err_msg = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(200), @LastName);
    RAISERROR('The "Single / Last Name" param provided is too short: %s',16,1, @err_msg);
    RETURN;
END
```

My proc was not failing. When I used LTRIM and RTRIM like below it did fail

```
IF DATALENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(@LastName))) < 2
BEGIN
    SELECT @err_msg = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(200), @LastName);
```

RAISERROR('The "Single / Last Name" param provided is too short: %s',16,1, @err_msg); 
    END

There is a more solid way to code the procedure by providing the a return value for error and clean execution. Then Grab the return value in .Net and evaluate it. Below is modified stored procedure to demonstrate what I mean.

```
CREATE Procedure dbo.TestError @LastName Char(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @err_msg nvarchar(200)
IF DATALENGTH(LTRIM(RTRIM(@LastName))) < 2
BEGIN
    SELECT @err_msg = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(200), @LastName);
    GOTO ErrorExit   
END

CleanExit:
BEGIN 
  RETURN 0
END

ErrorExit:
BEGIN
   RAISERROR('The "Single / Last Name" param provided is too short: %s',16,1, @err_msg);
    RETURN 1;
END
END
```